# case statement based on 3 columns in 1 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a field in my sql code where if the MRN value in row 1 and 2 are the same and the corresponding TF_GROUP is identical but the PathId field for both rows is different then the new field should have a 'Yes' otherwise it should default to 'No'. I can create this field in excel but am struggling to create something similar in sql. I have included the excel statement that i have written which i would ideally like to replicate in a sql statement below.

```
=IF(AND(B2=B3,D2=D3,A2<>A3),"Yes","No")
```

I basically want a sql syntax similar to the excel function above that I could use in sql server to create the column that i desire.

Below is the sql code that i have written with the 3 fields (PathID, MRN, TF_GROUP).

```
 select DISTINCT 
[Pathway ID] PathID,
MRN,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY mrn ORDER BY [Pathway ID]) RK,
[Treatment Function Group] TF_GROUP,
'' [Flag]

from [HRS_RTT].[dbo].[tbl_PMM_IncompletePTL_CG_Snapshot] 
where convert(date,censusdate) between '03-jun-19' and '09-jun-19'
AND MRN IS NOT NULL
AND [Treatment Function Group] IS NOT NULL

order by
MRN,
[Pathway ID]
```

Here is part of the output (see link below) after running the embedded sql code. The column called 'Flag' is what I am struggling to replicate in my sql code above. At the moment, i am having to copy the output into excel and then populate the 'Flag' column using the function i previously included in my previous post.

[image]

Comment: thank you to all that responded to my question but I don't think i was being explicit enough with the question so i have improved it and hoping a more relevant answer could be obtained on this forum.

Comment: You may create a function to get the PathID by MRN and RK, and then compare the PathID of RK=1 and RK=2 and set the flag value using CASE statement.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN B2 = B3 AND D2 = D3 AND A2 <> A3 THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END AS SomeColumnName
FROM SomeTable
```

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

A case expression will work as in the answer that Han gave. You can also use an IIF if you only have a simple IF/ELSE condition.

```
SELECT IIF(B2 = B3 AND D2 = D3 AND A2 <> A3, 'Y', 'N') as SomeColumnName
From SomeTable
```

If you have multiple conditions to test for (IF THEN/IF THEN/IF THEN/ELSE), then a CASE is much more practical than using nested IIFs

Comment: _"َA `CASE` **expression** . . ."_

Comment: @Sami, yes, expression. Getting my c# terms mixed up with my SQL terms...

Comment: CASE is also standard SQL and IFF is not.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to create a field

You can add a computed column as

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName
ADD NewColumnName AS CASE WHEN B2=B3 AND D2=D3 AND A2<>A3 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END;
```

Comment: altering the table seems a bit overboard don't you think?

Comment: @Hogan It's up to the OP needs, I'm just answering as I understand from the question. Nothing more.

Comment: OK, let me state that is a less gentle way:  I've been answering SQL on this site for almost 10 years and *every* time I see a user that is new to SQL ask how to "create a field" that does something they are not asking how to alter the table.  They don't have the vocabulary or understand to ask how to select this a value with this logic.  I've seen this more than I can count.

Comment: @Hogan Mybe you're right, but the OP has two good answers for selecting the data (mine is the last one) and mine is just in case he want to create a computed column.

Comment: I understand the logic but just pointing out: THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Y'.

Comment: @Zorkolot - he is just a positive person; the answer is always YES! :)

Answer (score 0):

What none of the other answers have addressed is: this question is about making comparisons across rows. The question is how to duplicate this Excel formula in SQL:

```
=IF(AND(B2=B3,D2=D3,A2<>A3),"Yes","No")
```

Note, for example, that `B2` refers to column B on row 2 while `B3` refers to column B on row **3**.

Here is a solution to your problem as described. It uses the T-SQL `LEAD` function to compare across rows. Note that I did not include the `DISTINCT` criteria from your original query as it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish with that.

However, I don't think this is necessarily how you want to do this. Comparing across rows is not normally something you do in SQL. You may want to give some more thought to your requirements and see if you can come up with a better way to fulfill them.

```
select
    PathID,
    MRN,
    TF_Group,
    case
        when MRN = Next_MRN and TF_Group = Next_TF_Group and PathID <> Next_PathID then 'Yes'
        else 'No'
    end as Flag
from (
    select
        [Pathway Id] as PathID,
        MRN,
        [Treatment Function Group] as TF_Group,

        lead([Pathway Id]) over (order by MRN, [Pathway ID]) as Next_PathID,
        lead(MRN) over (order by MRN, [Pathway ID]) as Next_MRN,
        lead([Treatment Function Group])  over (order by MRN, [Pathway ID]) as Next_TF_Group
    from tbl_PMM_IncompletePTL_CG_Snapshot
) x
order by MRN, PathID
```

Note that this answer is essentially a duplicate of the one I posted on the question that was marked as duplicate. I moved it here to prevent it from getting lost and so that anyone who finds this question will have this answer.